# Set window's owner without activating/bringing to front

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I've been googling for days for how to set window's owner without activating/bringing owner to front and couldn't manage to find it. Currently I'm using winapi:

```
SetWindowLong(hwndWindow, GWL_HWNDPARENT, hwndOwner); // GWL_HWNDPARENT = -8
```

or built in wrap:

```
new WindowInteropHelper(window) { Owner = owner };
```

Both works fine for setting owner, but they are bringing owner window to front which causes problems when there are a lot of windows.

Thanks for help!

Comment: A window is always in front of its owner. That's a primary design aspect of ownership.

Comment: The problem was that owner itself is brought to front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped:

> Please see:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
>   Pay attention for the note in "Remarks" about the requirement to
>   change the styles and synchronize the UISTATE.
>   —SA   Permalink
>   Sergey Alexandrovich